# How to weight a random float?

Tags: probability

Let's assume a random variable $X$, which is preferably in a range $[a,b]$, such that $a,b,X \in \Bbb{R}$. Any float on the range is equiprobable. Now, I have a function $f(x)$ defined on the range $[a,b]$ , which maps each value of $x$ to a weight (if needed, $f$ can be divided by $(\int_a^bf)\neq0$ to make it into the probability density function $g$). How would I go about computing a variable $Y$, such that it follows the probability density of $g$, given $X$ and $f$ or $g$?

I already tried searching the internet, but all I could find is about integers... (Also, for information, this is to be used in a program I wanna do later)

Comment: In other terms, I want to convert from a linear distribution to a distribution according to f'.

Comment: The answers that have been given may be all that you need now, but you may also be interested in Hörmann et al.'s [Automatic Nonuniform Random Variate Generation](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540406525), especially since the word "float" (rather than "real") suggests you're interested in a computer application.  There are other books (on Monte Carlo modeling methods, for example) that have chapters on similar material, but I suspect that some of the methods in this book can't easily be found elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DavidK's answer is the most general, but if you know something about $f$, and it's not too ugly, there's a very nice trick called "rejection sampling". It assumes that the function $f$ is always nonnegative (as the word "weight" suggests).

Here's the "picture":

Graph $f$ on the interval $[a, b]$; let's assume that the results come out between $0$ and $d$, so that the graph of $f$ lies entirely in the rectangle $R = [a, b] \times [0, d]$.

Now do the following:

1. using your favorite uniform random number generator, generate a pair $(x, y)$ in the rectangle $R$.
2. Check whether $y \le f(x)$. If so, return $x$ as your "sample". If not, return to step 1.

As I say, if $f$ is nice (like $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ on the interval $[0, 1]$), then life is good: you'll end up "returning to step 1" only a few times per sample. If $f$ is bad, like $f(x) = \exp(-200x)$ on the interval $[0, 1]$, then you'll end up returning to step 1 billions of times per sample.

A short description of "nice" is "not too spiky".

By the way, when you pick $d$, the upper bound for the $y$-values in your rectangle, you could clearly replace it with $d+1$ or $200 d$ and everything would still work. But you'll have the fewest "rejections" (i.e., returns to step 1) if $d$ is the least upper bound of the set $\{f(x) \mid x \in [a, b \}$, i.e., if $d$ is chosen as small as possible while still making sense. For $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ on the unit interval, we see that $f(x) \le 2$, and $f(1) = 2$, so picking $d = 2$ is ideal.

Comment: Thx that's really good, but i like the generality of @DavidK's answer. I might use your answer tho, as it is probably the easiest to implement, so that's why i accepted your answer

Comment: I'm glad to see this accepted, because it is a good alternative to inverse transform sampling in many cases. "Easy to implement" is a powerful argument.

Comment: I think we're all in agreement here. Both methods are widely used in computer graphics (which is where I first learned about them...or more honestly, where I first derived David's method for myself, and then learned that there was an easier way), and the secret sauce is in knowing which one will work out best for you. You can also add "stratification" to either one to improve things (with respect to some measures), but that also adds complexity.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing sounds like a *probability density function*. I'll use $g$ for what you called $f$. Suppose $g : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and
$$
\int_a^b f(t)\, dt = 1.
$$
Then you are saying: Instead of considering $X$, which is uniformly distributed on $[a,b]$ ('all numbers equiprobable'), let's suppose we have a random variable $Y$ which is distributed according to the probability density function $g$, which means that if $S \subset [a,b]$, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}\bigl( Y \in S \bigr) = \int_S g(t)\, dt.
$$

- There isn't really such a thing as "computing a random variable" because it is, well, random! You have to ask questions about it that are probabilistic or ask questions about it's statistics (like its expectation or variance).

Comment: More generally, if $f$ integrates to $K \neq 1$ over the interval $[a, b]$, but $f$ is non-negative everywhere (and non-zero somewhere), then you can use $\bar f(x) = f(x)/K$ instead of $f$, and it will work out like above. (This is more in line with how a weighted average is usually defined, IME.)

Comment: Thx for your answer... indeed, my unction can be seen as (or at least tweaked to be) a probability density fuction. But my question might not have been clear... I'm going to edit it so it is easier to understand what I want. Still, thank you

Comment: But this is what my answer is saying... I'll edit the answer now to use your notation (though $f'$ is not advised since the dash represents differentiation of a function on the real line)

Comment: Right at the end of your question, you use the word 'given'... are you trying to ask something about a conditional distribution?

Answer (score 2):

Similar questions have been asked here many times before,
but strangely enough I have been unable to find one that asked about this in such a general fashion.

The general method for solving this is *inverse transform sampling.*
Assuming $f$ is the probability density function of the distribution that you want to simulate, where $f$ is non-zero on the open interval $(a,b)$
but is zero on $(-\infty,a)$ and $(b,\infty).$
Find the cumulative distribution function $F$ by integration:

$$ F(y) = \int_a^y f(t)\,dt. $$

Since $f$ is a probability density, the range of $F$ is $[0,1].$

Next, find the inverse function of $F$ over the interval $[0,1].$ That is, find the function $F^{-1}$ such that
$F^{-1}(x) = y$ if and only if $F(y) = x.$

You do all of this once, before generating any random numbers,
and write the function $F^{-1}$ into your program.
At runtime, your program should draw the random variable $U$ from the interval $[0,1],$ and then set

$$ Y = F^{-1}(U). $$

Most software environments that offer built-in random number generation offer a RNG that gives a uniform distribution over floating-point numbers in $[0,1].$
You can use that to generate $U.$

If you are forced to use a function that generates a random number $X$ uniformly distributed in some other interval instead, such as the interval $[a,b],$
convert it to a variable uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ so that you can use it in the formula above:

$$ U = \frac{X - a}{b - a}. $$

Note that finding $F$ is often very difficult, and finding $F^{-1}$ can also be very difficult. There may not be good "exact" methods.
In some cases (such as a normal distribution, aka a Gaussian),
specific procedures have been found that do not require computing $F^{-1}.$
But you would have to ask about a specific distribution to find out whether such a procedure is known.

Here are some other questions that have similar answers:

[Generate an observation from a uniform (0,1) given a density function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774920/generate-an-observation-from-a-uniform-0-1-given-a-density-function)

[Find Random Number Generator following the density $f (x) = \frac{1 + \alpha x}{2}$, $ −1 ≤ x ≤ 1$, $−1 ≤\alpha ≤ 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3033771/find-random-number-generator-following-the-density-f-x-frac1-alpha-x)

[Given only uniform distribution, using mathematical transformation to derive number draw from various distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917042/given-only-uniform-distribution-using-mathematical-transformation-to-derive-num?rq=1)

[Using random number generator to draw from population](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693316/using-random-number-generator-to-draw-from-population/693318#693318)

Comment: Thx that's exactly what I wanted!